# Align tableGrob to textGrob in grid

Tags: r, gridextra

I'm trying to align a tableGrob to the left of the grid, so that the table will be aligned to the title.
This is the code I'm using:

```
createTableGrob <- function(table){
# wrap
namesLegendTable <- warp_text(names(table), width = warpTextWidth)
table <- apply(table, MARGIN= c(1, 2), FUN = function(x)
  paste(strwrap(x, width = warpTextWidth),  collapse = "\n"))

# grob
tableGrob <- tableGrob(
  table,
  theme = myt,
  cols = namesLegendTable,
  rows = NULL
)

separators <- replicate(ncol(table) - 1,
                        segmentsGrob(x1 = unit(0, "npc"), gp=gpar(col = "white", lty=1)),
                        simplify=FALSE)

gtable::gtable_add_grob(tableGrob,
                        grobs = separators,
                        t = 1,
                        b = nrow(tableGrob),
                        l = seq_len(ncol(tableGrob)-1)+1)
}

tableGrob <- createTableGrob(table)
titlePwc <- textGrob(titlePwc,gp=gpar(fontsize=14, fontface=3), hjust=0, x=0.02)
g <- arrangeGrob(
    titlePwc,
    secTableGrob,
    ncol = 1
    )
```

This is the result:
[grid with text and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA22n.png)

I would like to adjust the table to the left so that it will be aligned with the text.
Any advice will be appreciated.